# call of overloaded function 'decomposeSentence(const string&)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, nmea

I am currently programming a NMEA Parser in C++, and have been given a few pre-declared functions. I'm testing each function as I go along, but I've hit a snag in programming the `decomposeSentence` function. The code for the function is as follows:

```
NMEAPair decomposeSentence(const string & nmeaSentence) {
    /* Extract each comma-separated value from the string, and place into an
     * array. */
    string newSentence = nmeaSentence;
    vector<string> sep = split(newSentence, ',');

    /* Extract the sentence type (e.g. GPGLL) from the vector, remove the "$",
     * and remove from the vector. */
    string sentenceType = sep[0];
    sentenceType.erase(sentenceType.begin());
    sep.erase(sep.begin());

    /* Extract the part of the vector containing the checksum, and discard the
     * checksum. Remove the part of the vector still containing the checksum,
     * and replace this with the newly created value. */
    string discardChecksum = sep.back();
    discardChecksum = discardChecksum.substr(0, discardChecksum.find("*"));
    sep.erase(sep.end());
    sep.push_back(discardChecksum);

    /* Combine the sentence type and the vector elements into a pair. */
    NMEAPair decomposedSentence = make_pair(sentenceType, sep);

    /* Return the decomposed sentence. */
    return decomposedSentence;
}
```

When I try running the function in `main()`, like so...

```
int main() {
    const string nmeaSentence = "$GPGGA,091138.000,5320.4819,N,00136.3714,W,1,0,,395.0,M,,M,,*46";
    NMEAPair decomposedSentence = decomposeSentence(nmeaSentence);
}
```

... the compiler throws the error `call of overloaded 'decomposeSentence(const string&)' is ambiguous'`.

I realise this is probably a very simple issue to troubleshoot, but I would appreciate it if anyone could help me solve it.

**Edit: full error message**

```
../gps/src/main.cpp:52:65: error: call of overloaded ‘decomposeSentence(const string&)’ is ambiguous
     NMEAPair decomposedSentence = decomposeSentence(nmeaSentence);
                                                                 ^
../gps/src/main.cpp:23:10: note: candidate: GPS::NMEAPair decomposeSentence(const string&)
 NMEAPair decomposeSentence(const string & nmeaSentence) {
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../gps/src/main.cpp:1:0:
../gps/headers/parseNMEA.h:47:12: note: candidate: GPS::NMEAPair GPS::decomposeSentence(const string&)
   NMEAPair decomposeSentence(const string & nmeaSentence);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:721: main.o] Error 1
04:00:01: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project GPS (kit: Desktop)
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @RSahu That's sorted it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have `using namespace GPS;` somewhere in your code. Because of that, `GPS::decomposeSentence` and the global `decomposeSentence` are being picked by the compiler as potential overloads.

You can resolve the problem by:

1. Removing the `using namespace GPS;` line, or
2. Putting the global function in another `namespace` and using it explicitly from that `namespace`.

---

```
namespace ThisFileNS
{
   NMEAPair decomposeSentence(const string & nmeaSentence) 
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

and use

```
NMEAPair decomposedSentence = ThisFileNS::decomposeSentence(nmeaSentence);
```

in `main`.